# Does Avraham invite one of his visitors inside?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, language, genesis-bereishith

I've a question regards the following phrase from Genesis 18:10: "וְשָׂרָה שֹׁמַעַת פֶּתַח הָאֹהֶל וְהוּא אַחֲרָיו". 
"And Sarah was listening at the opening of the tent, and it was behind him." 
"And Sarah heard it in the tent door which was behind him." 
"And Sarah heard from the entrance of the tent, and it was behind him." 
"Sarah heard him from the entrance of the tent, behind him."

That Sarah was listening is clear, but putting the second part in translation I get: "The tent opened and he followed".

Could it be that he was invited insite? Which causes him to see her smiling?

Comment: "And Sarah heard from the entrance of the tent, and it (the door) was behind him (the angel). No mention there that the angel was invited inside.

Comment: פתח is vowelized as a noun, not a verb. Where are you getting this translation from?

Comment: @DonielF Rabbi Bachai ben Asher: The reason the Torah Scroll is not vowelized, is so that a person could interpret as they wish. For the letters, when they are not vowelized, contain within them many intentions and split into many sparks. And this is the reason the Torah scroll isn’t vowelized, because the meaning alluded to by each letter is determined by its vowel, and with a vowel only a single (small number) meaning can be determined. Without a vowel, however, a person can derive (from the text) a great number of exceedingly and wondrous and precious ideas.

Comment: @DonielF It was based the fact that without vowels the translator (doitingebrew.com) came up with this suggestion.

Comment: You confuse דרש with פשט. If you want the simple meaning of the pesukim, the answer is a resounding no. If you want to expound on the pesukim you can expound however you wish, but that's not the simple reading.

Answer (score 2):

[Vayeira 18:10](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8213/showrashi/true#v10)

> 10 And he said, "I will surely return to you at this time next year,
>   and behold, your wife Sarah will have a son." And Sarah heard from the
>   entrance of the tent, and it was behind him.

**Rashi**

> and it was behind him: The entrance was behind the angel.

Shows that the entrance to the tent (and Sarah was inside the entrance) was behind the malach. Thus had he been a human being he would have been unable to see her. Avraham was serving the malachim under the tree. That is why Sarah denied having laughed and saw that this was indeed not a human being and that what he said was a prophecy.